# How do I structure a class or a function/method (or interface) so that as part of a using, I can pass values in the {} brackets?

Tags: c#

How do I structure a class or a function/method (or interface) so that as part of a using, I can pass values in the {} brackets?

in the following:

```
using (var something = new SomeFunction(somevalue) { AnotherValue = anotherValue, AdditionalValue = adValue })
```

Comment: This is a valid syntax. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Your class has to inherit from `IDisposable` this way you can use `using`. The `{}` can be used with public properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is completely valid. You can write your `use` clause as:

```
public class SomeClass: IDisposable
{
    public SomeClass(object somevalue) {
    }

    public int AnotherValue { get; set; }

    public int AdditionalValue { get; set; }

    internal void ImHere() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    object somevalue = null;
    using (var something = new SomeClass(somevalue) { AnotherValue = 1, AdditionalValue = 2 }) {
        something.ImHere();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the brackets `{}` you can set the public properties of that object after the constructor finished.

`AnotherValue` and `AdditionalValue` are properties of `SomeFunction`

It is called object initializers.

Comment: Yours is technically right and thank you, i'm accepting romanoza's as the answer because he provided code that I could use as is.  I did not know they were called initializers..  I wish i could accept both of your answers because the two answers combined = the full answer.